# JavaScript check excel document for matching numbers

Tags: javascript, excel, alasql

I have a simple input form where you type 6 numbers, when you click the button the JavaScript will check a excel document if the numbers you entered matches a row. if so you win if not you loose.

I cant workout how to check the spread sheet to query every row to see is the numbers match.

in the document column c to h has the 6 numbers.

How can i alter my code to check this document ?

Please see code bellow.

**Javascript**

```
var lotteryNumbers = alasql('SELECT * FROM XLSX("results")');

function EnterNumber()
{
    var person = prompt("Please enter your raffle number");

    if(person != null)
    {
        checkIfYouHaveWinningNumber(person);
    }
}

function checkIfYouHaveWinningNumber(number)
{
    if(contains(number))
    {
        alert("Congratulation you won - " + number);
    }
    else
    {
        alert("You lose - " + number);
    }
}

function contains(number)
{
    for(var i = 0;i < lotteryNumbers.length;i++)
    {
        if(lotteryNumbers[i] == number)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: You better could see the ALASQL querying document to add the condition instead of looping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this - ALASQL has the very good querying feature

The example like below could be helful to query the table

https://jsfiddle.net/gt2osvha/

```
console.clear()

var data = [{a:1,b:10}, {a:21,b:20}, {a:111,b:30}];
var num = window.prompt();
if(num) {
    var q = "SELECT a FROM ? WHERE a=" + num;
    if(alasql(q,[data]).length > 0){
      alert("you won"); 
   } else {
   alert("lost");
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

var query= SELECT * FROM XLSX("results")
this query will give you 2-D array, that is row and column values, if your number is on first column, then

now use following:

```
function contains(number)
{
    for(var i = 0;i < lotteryNumbers.length;i++)
    {
        if(lotteryNumbers[1][i] == number)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Sorry Im not sure I understand. I need to look at all rows and see if colum c to h numbers match the numbers input by the user

Comment: then iterate it by i and j loop